# Why am I not able to re-assign a value to a dictionary element but can append to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key

I have a requirement where I have to basically reverse `keys` and `values` in a dictionary.

If the `key` is already present, it should append the new element value to the existing one.

I wrote a code for this. It is working fine. But if I re-assign the dictionary item instead of appending it, with a new element, instead of overwriting, it is creating `None` in place of value.

Here is the **working** code:

```
def group_by_owners(files):
    dt = {}
    for i,j in files.items():
        if j in dt.keys():
            dt[j].append(i) # Just appending the element
        else:
            dt[j]=[i]
    return dt

files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}   
print(group_by_owners(files))
```

> Correct Output: {'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt']}

Here is the code that is giving **wrong** output:

```
def group_by_owners(files):
    dt = {}
    for i,j in files.items():
        if j in dt.keys():
            dt[j] = dt[j].append(i) # Re-assigning the element. This is where the issue is present.
        else:
            dt[j]=[i]
    return dt

files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}   
print(group_by_owners(files))
```

> Incorrect Output: {'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': None}

I'm not sure if there will be any difference between re-assigning the dictionary element value and appending the existing value.

Someone, please clarify.

Comment: `append` works in-place so returns `None` to `dt[j] = dt[j].append(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your for loop:

```
for i,j in files.items():
        if j in dt.keys():
            dt[j] = dt[j].append(i) # Re-assigning the element. This is where the issue is present.
        else:
            dt[j]=[i]
```

TO

```
for key, value in files.items():
    # if dictionary has same key append value
    if value in list(dt.keys()):
        dt[value].append(key)
    else:
        dt[value] = [key]
```

**OR**

Add an item to the end of the list. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x]

```
for key, value in files.items():
    if value in list(dt.keys()):
        dt[value][len(dt[value]):] = [key]
    else:
        dt[value] = [key]
```

**O/P:**

```
{'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

[More details list append method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I was asking for the difference between those two which is what @roganjosh explained

Comment: That's exactly what they already had. The question is why the second version didn't  work